# Server sent events with Nancy

Tags: c#, .net, nancy, server-sent-events

How do I create server sent events with Nancy. I got only to return a single line, but I am not sure how to trigger the new events in my code.

This is what I have so for in my module:

```
 Get["/events"] = _ =>
 {        
  return Response.AsText(string.Format("data: {{\"date\":{0}}}\n\n", DateTime.Now.Ticks), "text/event-stream");
 };
```

Comment: Please how did you get this to work eventually?

Comment: I did not use server sent events at the end. I just used SignalR and SignalR automatically negotiate the transport it is going to use between client and server. Have a look at the [github link](https://github.com/damianh/NancySignalrOwin) posted below by @TheCodeJunkie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably use Nancy + SignalR and host it on OWIN

Comment: SignalR looks good to me, but I am just curious how would one implement ServerSent events with Nancy

Comment: out of curiosity. why owin? what is the role of owin here?

Comment: out of the box Nancy does not support long connections. SignalR helps you bridge that. OWIN makes it so much easier to glue things together on the same HTTP pipeline. Here is a small sample that illustrates it https://github.com/damianh/NancySignalrOwin

Comment: I was not aware of that SingalR can do server sent events. Thanks for the suggestion of the repo

Answer (score 1):

No need for SignalR. This can be done with out of the box streams using a NancyModule implementation. Below is an example:

```
public class LogModule : NancyModule
{
    public LogModule()
    {
        Get["/log"] = GetLog;
    }

    private object GetLog(object args)
    {
        return new Response
        {
            ContentType = "text/event-stream",
            Contents = stream =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);

                    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Log("Test"));

                    if (!TrySendEvent(json, stream))
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private static bool TrySendEvent(string value, Stream stream)
    {
        try
        {
            var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("data: " + value + "\n\n");
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            stream.Flush();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `Nancy.Reaponse`, set `ContentType` to `text/event-stream`

```
public class ClockModule : NancyModule
{
    public ClockModule()
    {
        Get["/clock"] = (args) => {
            return new Response
            {
                ContentType = "text/event-stream",
                Contents = (Stream stream) =>
                {
                    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("retry: 1000\ndata: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\n\n");
                    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    stream.Flush();
                }
            };
        };
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="clock">1970-01-01</div>
<script>
new EventSource("/clock").onmessage = function(event) {
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = event.data;
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Chrome browser result at http://127.0.0.1:9487/clock:

```
retry: 1000
data: 2018/9/28 16:40:38
```